# __vdso_time missing from core utils?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, glibc

I built the latest glibc and now i'm having some trouble with functions in coreutils like `ls` or `cat` or anything else like `vim`.

My error is

```
-bash-4.0$ cat
cat: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
```

and I built, glibc without errors with the following configure

```
../glibc/configure --prefix=/home/ex/uid377/glibbuilt
```

On older versions, like 2.14, running the utilities results in a segmentation fault.

```
-bash-4.0$ ./pwd
./pwd: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./pwd)
-bash-4.0$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ex/uid377/glibc/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
-bash-4.0$ ./pwd
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

**Edit** 
Kernel Version

```
-bash-4.0$ uname -r
2.6.32.26-175.fc12.x86_64
```

Comment: What kernel version are you on? What distribution? And why do you need to build glibc by hand?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov The login node is Fedora 12 running the 2.6 kernel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having multiple versions of glibc on a single system is possible, but slightly tricky, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) answer. In particular, this:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ex/uid377/glibc/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

is *expected* to crash, because your `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` will not match your `libc.so.6`

> cat: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): ...

It's not clear how you built this `cat`, but it's most likely the exact same problem: you are picking some libraries from `/lib64`, and some from `/home/ex/uid377/glibc/lib`. Don't do that. You *must* link all the programs that will use `/home/ex/uid377/glibc/lib/libc.so.6` with `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/ex/uid377/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

You can trace which libraries are currently being loaded by running:

```
env LD_DEBUG=files,libs ./cat
```