# Calling C++ from Java, but Java loads the wrong Glibc version

Tags: java, c++, linux, java-native-interface, glibc

I am trying to call a C++ library from java side and have written necessary jni code. However, when my java code tries to load my C++ library via `System.loadLibrary`, it complains the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libmylib.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by libmylib.so)
```

I later found that it is because I have two different GLIBC versions on my system, and the default one is the older one, while `libmylib.so` is required to built from the newer GLIBC.  As a result, java links to the wrong GLIBC.

I tried the following things, but it does not work :(.

The first one is to try to load correct library manually via `System.load` in my java code.  Specifically, I added the following codes before it loads my library:

```
static {
  System.load("/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17/lib/libc.so.6");
  System.load("/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18");      
  System.loadLibrary(mylib);
}
```

The libc.so.6 is also added because libstdc++ depends on it (otherwise java will load the wrong libc and complains another error).  However, this time java complains the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
  /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-glibc2.17/lib/libc-2.17.so:
      __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
```

And this error is caused by mixing two versions of GLIBC as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668457/vdso-time-missing-from-core-utils).
The solution to that question is for building C++ program with `-Wl,--dynamic-linker` set properly (also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229)).  However, I don't know how to do that in Java.

I tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the newer version, but the situation is just the same :(.

Can I know how to make java link to the correct library?

(PS: a solution without make install newer version of glibc is preferred, since many other applications in my machine rely on the current default glibc)

I have been searching and trying solutions to my problem for days, but none of them succeed :(

Stackoverflow, you're my only hope :~.

Comment: "I tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the newer version," How did you do that?

Comment: Not sure if I did this right. I tried that by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_new_glib`, and also tried to do `java -Djava.library.path=path_to_new_glib`, but both complain the same `__vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument` error.

Comment: I guess that error message means your setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is effective.

Comment: I think so, but that error seems to be mixing two libraries together as the linked question suggests (the first question link also says simply changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH will produce this error.)  Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I think you should rebuild your `libmylib.so` to use the default Glibc in your system. This would be the simplest solution to your problem.

Comment: But the default one does not support `-std=c++11` while my library requires that :(.

Comment: Then you are in a much biger trouble. The reason of your problem is that the dynamic linker your program (maybe `java`) use does not match the `libc.so` it tries to load.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to make java to use the correct glib? even I manually force java to load the correct libc.so, it will still try to load other libraries from the incorrect glib :(

Comment: The path of dynamic linker is hard coded in executable, that is the problem.

Comment: By hard coded in executable, can I know which executable you refer to? is it the way I build my library wrong? or the executable is java?

Comment: In your case, I guess the executable is `java` itself. When `java` tries to load a dynamic library, it may use `dlopen()`, and it will use the same dynamic linker as the `java` using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `System.load("/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17/lib/libc.so.6");`

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617), this can not possibly work.

By the time you reach above statement, the *system* `libc.so.6` has already been loaded (at process startup), and you **absolutely can not** have two versions of `libc.so.6` loaded into the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LD_PRELOAD=new_c_library.so java -javastuff

Comment: Still encounter the same problem :~~ `java: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument`.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I wish people would stop suggesting `LD_PRELOAD` of `libc.so.6`. Just think about *which* code interprets `LD_PRELOAD` (hint: that code is in libc!).

Comment: @EmployedRussian: Isn't ld-linux.so built static? It's the dynamic linker, it can't require itself to run. Therefore, it shouldn't be pulling in libc symbols.

Comment: "Isn't ld-linux.so static" -- it's *complicated*. No, it is not completely static, as you can see by running `readlink -d ld-linux.so.2`. It also *does* pull `libc.so.6` symbols, as can be observed by running a binary under GDB, setting `catch syscall mmap64`, and looking at stack -- the first few calls will be executed by `ld-linux` directly, but subsequent calls will go through `libc.so.6`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: Its possible that it has changed, or options are different or something, but when I was doing a lot of Gentoo building in 2008 I am almost entirely certain ld-linux.so was static and didn't load anything. Because PRELOAD worked for me.