# Determine current glibc version from within Java

Tags: java, linux, glibc

For a java application running on a linux system, how can I determine the underlying version of glibc?

Background: I'd like to, at runtime, determine if it possible to use conscrypt, which appears to require glibc 2.14 nowadays (https://github.com/google/conscrypt/pull/589), but I would still need to gracefully support running on CentOS 6 or other older distributions by falling back to the standard Java SSL code. Unfortunately (at least as far as I've been able to determine) there's no way to catch and recover from the error that occurs if Conscrypt is initialised on an older distribution, but if I can determine the glibc version I could choose whether to initialise it based on that.

Comment: Run `ldd --version` command from Java and check the output. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20155150/5221149

Comment: Is there some official format to parse the output based on? Or failing that, is the output format known to be stable?

Comment: Maybe related, [Calling C++ from Java, but Java loads the wrong Glibc version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22550611/608639)

Answer (score 2):

Working example of executing `ldd --version` and parsing the response for the version number.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash").command("ldd --version");
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        final Process process = processBuilder.start();
        final StringBuilder stream = readStream(process.getInputStream());

        final String version = getVersion(stream.toString());

        System.out.println(version);
    }

    /**
     * Read the output stream of the process
     *
     * @param iStream InputStream
     * @return StringBuilder containing the output of the command
     */
    private static StringBuilder readStream(InputStream iStream) throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream))) {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }

        return builder;
    }

    /**
     * Parse the response for the version number.
     *
     * @param input String response of ldd --version
     * @return String of the version, or null if not found
     */
    private static String getVersion(String input) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to run the command in Bash rather than just running the command? What's the advantage to going through Bash?

Comment: And why do you care about the system line separator? Seems redundant to take text line by line then stick it back together just to parse it again. Wouldn't using a `List<String>` make more sense? Either that or just dump the output directly into a `String` without the intermediate splitting by line.

Comment: Sure, to be fair it was mostly a copy-paste and a wee tweak from a current project I have open. Didn't say it was production ready but it will do what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use some pre-built binary.  You should be able to catch the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception thrown by the [`java.lang.System.load(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)) method.  If the JNI shared object is linked correctly, the dynamic linker will detect the missing symbol versions (presumably `GLIBC_2.14`) even if lazy binding is active.

Alternatively, I don't see anything in Conscrypt which would preclude building on CentOS 6 (with the [Developer Toolset software collection](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/) for a C++11 compiler). It's a bit involved, but the glibc 2.14 dependency seems to be something that comes from the way the pre-built binaries are made, and it's not inherent to the software itself.