# not able to import tensorflow inside anaconda python 2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow

First of all,  I am an inexperienced with most things related to software engineer, so bear with me if the question is too simple.

On my windows desktop,  I installed VMware.  Inside the vmware,  I installed Anaconda.  then using the pip command I was able to install tensorflow.

However when I try to import it, the following error shows up

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:04:42) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.client_lib import *
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/client_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.session import InteractiveSession
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as tf_session
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
**ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)**
```

I can't find the GLIBC_2.17 anywhere, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The TensorFlow binary packages require that the installed version of `glibc` (the GNU C Library) is at least 2.17. It looks like your VM has an old version of `glibc`, which is causing this error when you try to load TensorFlow.

Since you are using VMWare, can you try creating a VM with a Ubuntu 14.04 image? We have tested with this operating system, and it has the necessary libraries to run TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

You can either ugprade your libc (see [Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.04. 'GLIBC_2.17 not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f) for example)

Or you could just build from source so that it uses your local version of libc.  The latter is probably the easiest way to go.  See http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#installing_from_sources

(When you configure, say no to using GPU to keep things simple)

Comment: The provided link is broken now .. this could help https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources