# Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 in Red Hat release 6.6. 'GLIBC_2.17 not found'

Tags: python, python-2.7, redhat, glibc, tensorflow

This is essentially a repeat of question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f). However, I am using Red Hat Version 6.6, which has glibc 2.12 (glibc 2.17, I think was introduced with RHEL ver 7). Is it possible to install tensorflow locally, without upgrading OS. (I don't have admin privileges). This is the error I am getting

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /data02/storage/kgupt33/.local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

Comment: Can you just update glibc?

Comment: Updating system glibc, will require the whole OS upgrade (I checked that with sys admin). I tried installing glibc locally, but that also requires upgrading tons of system libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.04. 'GLIBC\_2.17 not found'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f)

Comment: Upvoted - I am also getting this error - and was hoping to get a local/user install of the glibc-2.17/ld.so too. I'm not admin on a Red Hat 4.4.6-3 - and help welcome!

Comment: I have the same issue and I m really curious how to fix it... without upgrading the whole OS.

Answer (score 1):

> This is essentially a repeat of question asked here.

And the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658956/50617) should work. What stops you from downloading glibc-2.17 packages, unpacking them, and using the `glibc-2.17/ld.so` with correct `--library-path`?

> Is it possible to install tensorflow locally, without upgrading OS.

Yes, using above answer.

Comment: I downloaded glibc's latest version, but compiling it requires updating a lot of libraries (like gcc, binutils, etc.). Are you asking me to use a precompiled version?