# Installing Tensorflow on centos 5

Tags: python, centos, glibc, tensorflow, binutils

I'm trying to install Tensorflow on Centos 5.
Unfortunatelly, after having installed it with pip as explained in the official doc

> sudo pip install --upgrade
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

I have the following error when I try to import tensorflow on a python shell

> ImportError:
>   /home/users/caohao/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so:
>   ELF file OS ABI invalid

The following issue on github gave me a lead:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/350

Actually, tensorflow requires glibc version to be at least 2.17

When I type

> ldd --version

I have the following output:

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.5
```

So I need to upgrade glibc. 
I would like to perform a "parallel" installation, because upgrading glibc could be dangerous for my machine
So I downloaded the source, and I use the command

> ../glibc-2.18/configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.18

to install it in an other directory

The problem is that I have the following error when I launch configure

> configure: error: assembler too old, .cfi_personality support missing

I think I have to update binutils as well, so I downloaded the sources and install it in /opt/binutils-2.26/ to not harm the system.

Yet I still have the same error when I try to configure glibc.

Here are my questions:

How can I specify which version of binutils I want to use to build glibc ?

EDIT: I should have RTFM, answer is use ‘--with-binutils=directory’ option

How can I make tensorflow looking for the good version of glibc when it will be installed in /opt/glibc-2.18 ?

FYI I use python 2.7.11

Thank you very much and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same problem.

But I used CentOS 6.5 and my GLIBC(GNU libc) version is 2.12.

I tried to changed my GLIBC version manually by removing version 2.12 and installing 2.17.

It occured many problems for it's dependencies and cannot import TensorFlow.

So, I used **CentOS 7.0 and it has default GLIBC version 2.17.**

I can install and run TensorFlow using CentOS 7.0 without any problem.

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

I think tensorflow needs exactly GLIB 2.17
and not 2.18. 
For some reason it got hardcoded.

See also:
[Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.04. 'GLIBC_2.17 not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f/33658956#33658956)

Comment: Thank you , 
Anyway I think CentOS 5.6 is too old for running Tensorflow, I updated half of GNU libraries to compile GLIBC 2.17 (GCC, GMP, MPFR, MPC...) and now it seems the linux kernel is too old...