# failed to run tensorflow because of glibc

Tags: tensorflow, glibc

I just want to install the tensorflow using pip.
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
and it succeed.

And I run python -c "import tensorflow;it will report
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /usr/local/python2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)

And I tried to upgrade GLIBC_2.15,and then now it reported that
ImportError: /opt/glibc-2.15/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /usr/local/python2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.s

And then tried to upgrade to GLIBC_2.17,and then type ls ,the error as below:
ls: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument

My machine is 
Linux sjs_88_78 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 29 10:16:43 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Might be similar to [Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 ... 'GLIBC_2.17 not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f?rq=1)