# Segmentation fault(core dumped) while weakening dependencies on glibc2.17

Tags: centos, segmentation-fault, tensorflow, linux-mint

I am installing tesorflow on remote system server. This has centos installed. I am not admin , so I had to install tensorflow within a virtual environment. Once I did that then I encountered - import Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.04. 'GLIBC_2.17 not found'
Then I followed the post-: ***[Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.04. 'GLIBC_2.17 not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f)***
Finally the error did changed to weak version GLIBC_2.17 not found but no matter what I do I always get segmentation fault. It doesn't matter what is the code.
I don't have admin rights- the server is CENTOS. I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: Did you try building from source? I think tf doesn't have any pre-build binaries for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: No, I just used pip install

Comment: But the point is that how to install from source within a virtual environment

Comment: When you install from source, you build `//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`, that creates a pip package for your system, which you can then install in virtualenv using pip