# setting LD path for submitting job via qsub to a remote cluster Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, remote-server, qsub

I am trying to use tensorflow on a cluster with outdated GLIC library.

I have tried following the steps explained in this page: [Error while importing Tensorflow in python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.04. 'GLIBC_2.17 not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f/34897674#34897674)
It works when I run it with a normal python command (which python = /anaconda2/bin/python)

I need to run my program using the qsub command (script submission) in the cluster but I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/k15/helloada.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/users/k15/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/users/k15/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/users/k15/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/users/k15/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /users/k15/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

The problem is that I cannot use the following line:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/" $HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so `which python`
```

with the qsub command. (I can make tensorflow work normally by running python with the above line.)
The qsub uses a script file with the following structure:

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=/users/k15/file.py 

EXEC=home/k15/anaconda2/bin/python 

$EXEC $INPUT
```

I am at a loss on how to make this work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I never used _TensorFlow_ but why not editing the shell script and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just before `$EXEC $INPUT`?

Comment: Hi cristifati, do you mean copypasting the ld_library_path line that I included in my question as a new line in the script file?

Comment: Yes, add that line before the last line in your script at the end of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much it seems to be working!