# error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory when installing tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

This is my computing environment: `Ubuntu 16.04+gcc4.9.3+gtx 1080+cuda 8.0RC+cudnn 5.1v`. I am trying to compile Tensorflow from source through Bazel. But I keep getting this error `error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory`. How do I fix it?[image]

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39181639/1032586

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tensorflow build failure with gcc error 'as'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095577/tensorflow-build-failure-with-gcc-error-as)