# FMI - C standard library version differences cause linking errors

Tags: linker, glibc, dynamic-linking, undefined-reference, fmi

I have a [publicly-available FMU](https://trac.fmi-standard.org/browser/branches/public/Test_FMUs#FMI_2.0/ModelExchange/linux32/OpenModelica/v1.11.0/RoomHeating_OM_RH) for which I am trying to link the embedded .so file with the rest of my program. (This is contained within the .fmu file if you view as an archive.) During the linking phase I am getting the following undefined reference errors:

`RoomHeating_OM_RH.so: undefined reference to '__longjmp_chk@GLIBC_2.11'`

`RoomHeating_OM_RH.so: undefined reference to '__fread_chk@GLIBC_2.7'`

If I look at the content of RoomHeating_OM_RH.so with a tool like `nm -a`, I see lots of undefined references of this form that aren't causing errors at link time. Here are a couple such lines from the `nm -a` output:

`U __vsnprintf_chk@@GLIBC_2.3.4`

`U _setjmp@@GLIBC_2.0`

However, the ones that are causing errors are differentiated from the rest of them by the fact that they have newer versions of GLIBC in the name. Here's what I have in my /lib dir for the libc library (yes I realize these are old versions, but it's what I am stuck with for now):

`/lib/libc-2.5.so`

`/lib/libc.so.6`

So my guess is that I don't have a new enough version of libc to link against. Is it a requirement that the version of libc be exactly what the .so file calls out? Or does it only need to be equal to or newer than the version called out? Furthermore, does the FMI specification even cover this aspect of compatibility? Or does it assume that *IF* .so files are provided in the FMU that they MUST be compiled using the same or older versions of libraries as will be installed on the target machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my guess is that I don't have a new enough version of libc to link against.

Correct.

> Is it a requirement that the version of libc be exactly what the .so file calls out?

No. You need GLIBC-2.11 *or newer*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093059/50617) for explanation.

Comment: Thank you. This solves my first issue with library versions. However I am still interested in the FMI specification's lack of granularity at this level. It doesn't appear to be enough for the specification to cover "libraries" when the specific content of those libraries will determine whether the FMI is compatible with the target environment. It seems like it should define those details as well.

Comment: I would expect exporters to provide such dependency information in the index.html documentation contained in the FMU.