# undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_setname_np@@GLIBC_2.12' Haskell Stack error on OpenSuse42.3

Tags: haskell, opensuse, haskell-stack

I have installed haskell stack and I'm trying to setup ghc for the same. stack version is

```
stack --version
Version 1.5.1, Git revision 600c1f01435a10d127938709556c1682ecfd694e (4861 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.1
```

I have updated the ~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml as below

```
# This is the implicit global project's config file, which is only used when
# 'stack' is run outside of a real project.  Settings here do _not_ act as
# defaults for all projects.  To change stack's default settings, edit
# '/home/rajkumar/.stack/config.yaml' instead.
#
# For more information about stack's configuration, see
# http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/
#
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages: []
extra-deps: []
resolver: ghc-8.2.1
```

Then I run stack setup command and got the below error -

```
  stack setup
  The GHC located at /home/rajkumar/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.2.1/bin/ghc failed to compile a sanity check. Please see:

  http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/

  for more information. Exception was:
  Running /home/rajkumar/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.2.1/bin/ghc /tmp/stack-sanity-check3048/Main.hs -no-user-package-db in directory /tmp/stack-sanity-check3048/ exited with ExitFailure 1

  [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack-sanity-check3048/Main.hs, /tmp/stack-sanity-check3048/Main.o )
  Linking /tmp/stack-sanity-check3048/Main ...

 /usr/bin/ld.bfd: /home/rajkumar/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.2.1/lib64/ghc-8.2.1/rts/libHSrts.a(OSThreads.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_setname_np@@GLIBC_2.12'
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `ldd --version`

Comment: ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.26
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

Comment: So maybe the problem is that you need `GLIBC_2.12` installed on your machine and not `2.26`

Comment: How did you install stack ?

Comment: by using command `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh` as mentioned in https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/

Comment: I was trying to downgrade glib from version 2.26 to 2.12 and unsuccessful :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So maybe the problem is that you need GLIBC_2.12 installed on your machine and not 2.26

No, that is *not* the issue. GLIBC-2.26 most certainly provides the `pthread_setname_np@@GLIBC_2.12` symbol (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093059/50617) to understand how symbol versioning works).

You can verify that the symbol is indeed available in your GLIBC-2.26 like so:

```
$ readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 | grep pthread_setname_np
    89: 00000000000113c0   258 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 pthread_setname_np@@GLIBC_2.12
   704: 00000000000113c0   258 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 pthread_setname_np
```

(Above command was executed on a system with GLIBC-2.19, but you'll get the same output on a system with GLIBC-2.26).

Now to what your *real* problem is: `libHSrts.a(OSThreads.o)` *references* `pthread_setname_np` (and likely other `pthread_*` symbols, but you are not linking with `-pthread` or `-lpthread` flag.

I don't know where to add this flag to GHC, but once you find that out, your problem will be solved.

Comment: I have created issue https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3472 for this.

Comment: Thanks Employed Russion for your kind suggestion. This issue is fixed now.