# How to change the glibc version required by an executable?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, glibc

```
ldd MyExecutable | grep libc
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007eff56bd0000)
```

This executable requires glibc version 2.25 from Ubuntu 18.04. How can I overwrite it do ask for glibc 2.23, which is the one present on ubuntu 16.04?

I'm aware of possible problems, but how can I do it?

Comment: The snippet you posted doesn't mention glibc 2.25

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk how should I know which version of glibc it looks for?

Comment: But you said you already know it: `This executable requires glibc version 2.25`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes but this is when I try to generate an AppImage. I'd like to know how to verify this and how to replace it

Answer (score 1):

To understand *why* your binary requires `GLIBC_2.25`, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093059/50617).

To understand how you can build a binary which requires older GLIBC version, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617).