# fcntl only function that uses glibc_2.28, rest use 2.4

Tags: linux, compilation, linker

`objdump -T | grep GLIBC_2` shows that all functions use GLIBC_2.4 except for `fcntl` which uses 2.28

How do I force `fcntl` to use an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I force fcntl to use an older version?

You need to compile and link against older version of GLIBC.

To understand how the linker decides which version to use, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093059/50617).