# NixOS newer GLIBC version forced by environment outside nix-shell

Tags: linux, glibc, nixos

My NixOS system is running on the current nixos-23.05 channel. But I'm using vscode from the current nixos-unstable channel in my configuration.nix like this:

```hs
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
let
  unstable = import <nixos-unstable> { config = { allowUnfree = true; }; };
in
{
# ...
  users.users.musteresel = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    description = "Daniel Jour";
    packages = with pkgs; [
      # ...
      unstable.vscode.fhs
    ];
  };
# ...
}
```

glibc version on the nixos-23.05 channel is 2.37, on the unstable channel it is 2.38.
**vscode is running fine without any issues!**

But if I open a terminal from within VS Code, go to some (C++ + cmake + nix shell) project directory of mine and do

```bash
nix-shell
cmake -S . -B build-from-vscode
cmake --build build-from-vscode
```

then I get an executable which somehow depends on GLIBC version 2.38 (through the `fmod` symbol, as reported by readelf and nm).

If I do the same from a "normal" (outside VS code) terminal:

```bash
nix-shell
cmake -S . -B build-outside
cmake --build build-outside
```

then I get an executable which does not depend on GLIBC 2.38.

**Where is this impurity coming from?** The versions of CMake, compiler and so on are the same (same nix store paths!) for both nix-shells (of course, since they're using the same shell.nix file and are both using packages from the nixos-23.05 channel).

*edit* The impurity seems to come from the environment variables `NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE`, `NIX_CFLAGS_LINK` and `NIX_LDFLAGS`, since they hold values that reference the fhs environment of vscode (with the newer glibc in it):

```bash
NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE=-idirafter /usr/include
NIX_CFLAGS_LINK=-L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib32
NIX_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib32
```

Using in my `shell.nix`:

```hs
  shellHook = ''
    unset NIX_LDFLAGS
    unset NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE
    unset NIX_CFLAGS_LINK
  '';
```

Solves this issue when running nix-shell from within vscode. But it does not solve the issue when running a build through vscode (with the nix-environment extension).

Comment: Note: no difference when using `nix-shell --pure`

Answer (score 1):

> Where is this impurity coming from?

I know *nothing* about nix-shell or vscode, but you can tell where the `GLIBC_2.38` reference is coming from by tracing which library provides the definition of the `fmod` symbol, which you can do by linking with `-Wl,-y,fmod` flag.

Undoubtedly your two builds are using *different* versions of `libm.so.6`. The "problem" build is using newer version of `libm.so.6` (and probably newer version of `math.h` as well), one which defines `fmod@@GLIBC_2.38`.

How the linker decides which symbol version to use is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093059/50617).