# Trouble with importing igraph-python

Tags: python, installation, conda

I have `CentOS release 6.8 (Final)` on my system. I have intalled the `igrph-python` by

```
conda install -c marufr python-igraph=0.7.1.post6
```

When I try to import the package I get the error:

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/abolfazl/.python-eggs/python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/igraph/_igraph.so)
```

I searched for similar questions and found some answers. I tried them like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34897674/784433).
But still, I get the `ImportError`.
Do you have any solution?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
conda install -yc nehaljwani python-igraph=0.7.1.post6
```

Okay, let's see which versioned dependencies exist for the shared library:

```
readelf --version-info /root/.cache/Python-Eggs/python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/igraph/_igraph.so | grep -Po '(?<=GLIBC_)([\d.]*)' | sort -Vr | head -1
2.14

readelf --version-info /root/.cache/Python-Eggs/python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/igraph/_igraph.so | grep -Po '(?<=GLIBCXX_)([\d.]*)' | sort -Vr | head -1
3.4.15
```

Let's see what the system provides:

```
strings /lib64/libc.so.6  | grep -Po '(?<=GLIBC_)([\d.]*)' | sort -Vr | head -1
2.12

strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -Po '(?<=GLIBCXX_)([\d.]*)' | sort -Vr | head -1
3.4.13
```

As you can see, `3.4.13` is < `3.4.15` and `2.12` is < `2.14` and hence the shared library `_igraph.so` doesn't load.

Okay, so you got some options:

Alternative 1: Use conda's gcc and libxml2 build to build the package.

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ libxml2-devel
bash Miniconda2-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/m2
source ~/m2/bin/activate
conda install -y conda-build
conda install -yc marufr python-igraph=0.7.1.post6
conda install -y gcc libxml2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/m2/lib/
conda build $CONDA_PREFIX/pkgs/python-igraph-0.7.1.post6-py27_0/info/recipe/
conda remove -y python-igraph
conda install $CONDA_PREFIX/conda-bld/linux-64/python-igraph-0.7.1.post6-py27_0.tar.bz2
python -c 'import igraph; print igraph.__version__'
0.7.1
```

Note here that I used gcc from conda, and I had to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so that while testing the package, it would pick `$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/libstdc++.so` instead of the system's `libstdc++.so`. So, the next time you use the package that you built yourself, you will have to install `gcc` using conda too. Meh, too much work.

Alternative 2: Build the package, but use system's gcc and libxml2

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ libxml2-devel
bash Miniconda2-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/m2
source ~/m2/bin/activate
conda install -y conda-build
conda install -yc marufr python-igraph=0.7.1.post6
conda build $CONDA_PREFIX/pkgs/python-igraph-0.7.1.post6-py27_0/info/recipe/
conda remove -y python-igraph
conda install $CONDA_PREFIX/conda-bld/linux-64/python-igraph-0.7.1.post6-py27_0.tar.bz2
python -c 'import igraph; print igraph.__version__'
0.7.1
```

Note that this time, I didn't have to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and depend on the old system libraries. Now, you don't require to install `gcc` using conda each time you use this package. But still, too much work, meh.

Alternative 3. Let pip do the compilation of the shared library: `_igraph.so`

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ libxml2-devel
bash Miniconda2-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/m2
source ~/m2/bin/activate
pip install python-igraph==0.7.1.post6
python -c 'import igraph; print igraph.__version__'
0.7.1
```

Alternative 4: I have built the package for you and put it on my channel. Feel free to use it :-)

```
bash Miniconda2-4.2.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/m2
source ~/m2/bin/activate
conda install -yc nehaljwani python-igraph=0.7.1.post6
python -c 'import igraph; print igraph.__version__'
0.7.1
```

Alternative 4 is the easiest as of now, but why does it work? Let's look at it's dependencies now:

```
readelf --version-info /root/.cache/Python-Eggs/python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/igraph/_igraph.so | grep -Po '(?<=GLIBCXX_)([\d.]*)' | sort -Vr | head -1
3.4

readelf --version-info /root/.cache/Python-Eggs/python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/igraph/_igraph.so | grep -Po '(?<=GLIBC_)([\d.]*)' | sort -Vr | head -1
2.7
```

As you can see, `3.4` is < `3.4.15` and `2.7` is < `2.12` and hence the shared library `_igraph.so` now loads with the system's old libraries :-)

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you.