# ERROR: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime in Python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, tensorflow

Here is the issue. This error FIRST occurred pointing to this

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /home/avijit/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

that I solved using this
[glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error)

BUT, now it has another similar problem

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /home/avijit/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

How to solve these issues? Why do they keep coming one after another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some dependencies for running TensorFlow.

You can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) tutorial to install TensorFlow from scratch.

Anyway, for your particular issue, you can just install `libc6`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

Comment: There's a problem though, as I forgot to mention, the dependency issues arise due to Ubuntu 12.04, where apt-cache policy for libc6 is till 2.15 only, unless there is a third party repo. Overall, I guess these issues do not hinder Ubuntu 14 and >. I found a solution [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f?rq=1) for Ubuntu 12.04