# ERROR, when compile tensorflow from source using bazel

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I am try to follow [lgor's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41003023/2803344), `Option 4 - Compile tensorflow from source`.
I didn't use root privilege, and I use `CentOS 7.0`, `python 3.5 in Anacoda3's virtual environment`.

I have tried `step 1-7`, so far so good. But when I try `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` (without GPU, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)) after `./configure`, I got following error:

```
ERROR: /mnt/home/xx/dl_tensor/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:168:1: null failed: protoc failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc '--python_out=bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/' -I. -Iexternal/protobuf/python -Ibazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python ... (remaining 38 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong with it, please give me a help!

Comment: Protoc is complaining that it cannot find the right glibc. What version of glibc do you have?

Comment: I have `GLIBC_2.12`