# How to determine the version of libc6 to be used with Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow on a machine that I do not have root access. I have followed all the steps and the installation has been successful. However, when I try to import Tensorflow in Python, I get an error that an old version of libc6 is installed.

I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34897674/6753906), but I could only get it to work once and I am not able to use the same solution now.

It looks like there are two versions of libc6 installed on the machine: the first one is `/lib64/libc6.so` and the other one is `/usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3`. Apparently, TF uses the first one which has an older version of libc6 and returns an error `ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found.`

How can I force TF to use the second library, which is a more recent version of libc6, in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Run the command `ldd --version` in your terminal. What version of glibc does it say you have?

Comment: It says: "ldd (GNU libc) 2.12"

Comment: OK, I have run into a similar issue before. Basically you are not meeting the core dependency for glibc, which is an OS thing. Is there any chance that you can update the OS? Because that is the easiest solution. Otherwise you have to try to run a different version of glibc locally and point TF to that, which is difficult and hacky.