# Trensorflow installation issue: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in a ubuntu machine running on oracle virtualbox within a windows PC.

System Details:
Host OS: windows7 - 32 bit
VM: Oracle virtuabox
VM OS: Ubuntu -  64 bit

**Steps followed for tensor flow installation:**
1. Created a session tflow with conda and python 3.5
2. Activated "tflow"
3. Installed tensorflow through pip
4. Tried to import tensorflow with the following command after installation:
 import tensorflow as tf

**System threw the following error:**

> import tensorflow as tf 
>   Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in  
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in  
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper 
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module 
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic 
>       return _load(spec) 
>   ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "", line 1, in  
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in  
>       from tensorflow.python import * 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in  
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in  
>       raise ImportError(msg) 
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in  
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in  
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper 
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module 
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) 
>     File "/home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic 
>       return _load(spec) 
>   ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/sethu/conda3/envs/tflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)
>
> *Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.*
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Please help!

Thanks
Sethu

Comment: Seems you are missing GLIBC; what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: See here for some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f

Answer (score 0):

may you use jupyter notebook?
There is all file you required have been already install.