# Is it possible to lock versions of packages in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda 3 2.3.0 on Windows xp. It is supposed to be the [last version of anaconda to support windows xp](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-winxp-with-proxy.html) as it contains python 3.4.3, and python 3.4.x is the last version of python to support windows xp.

When installing a package with

> conda install

,one of its dependencies was updating conda to conda 4.x. conda 4.x crashed in the commandline when running conda install . This made anaconda unusable that i uninstalled anaconda.

My question, is it possible to lock versions of packages ? For the two use cases:

- lock and forget : for packages I never want them to update, i need to run a command to lock them once so they will never update as a depency
- ignore updating : install a package while ignoring to update certain package passed by name in this update.

If only one of the 2 use cases is possible or is known or is easier, please write it as answer.

Comment: And for Windows 7 you need to pin `python 3.8`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two bits to this. First, you can prevent conda from auto-updating by changing the configuration option [`auto_update_conda` to `False`](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#update-conda-automatically-auto-update-conda):

```
conda config --set auto_update_conda False
```

The other bit is to pin packages to certain versions. For those packages you don't want to update, you can pin the version by adding a line to a file called `pinned` (you might need to create it) in the environment's `conda-meta` directory. The syntax is

> [The code] below [placed in `conda-meta/pinned`] forces NumPy to stay on the 1.7 series, which is any version that starts with 1.7, and forces SciPy to stay at exactly version 0.14.2:
>
> ```
> numpy 1.7.*
> scipy ==0.14.2
> ```

See [the documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) for more information.

Comment: The first command that disables auto update of conda works on conda 5.0.1 but not on conda 2.3.0

Comment: however the second trick - the one with pinned file- works. I put conda in pinned file to disable its updates and it works! It now generates 'Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.' when installation requires updating conda.

Comment: I couldn't pin the python binary that I built myself even with your solutions.
For example, even when I do this `conda install numpy  ... python=3.6.3-0`, my conda tries `python:         3.6.3-0    ...torch_fork/conda-bld --> 3.6.3-h6c0c0dc_5`

Comment: You can pin the channel of a package, but I'm not sure how to do that. Please ask a new question and include your complete input and output

Comment: I pinned two packages to pip builds because conda builds [were failing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628478/974555), with `llvmlite==0.27.0-pypi` and `numba==0.42.0-pypi`.

Comment: echo $CONDA_PREFIX can be used to lookup your env where you can add to `conda-meta/pinned`

Answer (score 1):

Pin for `conda install` (=): `package=1.0`

vs.

Pin for `pip install` (==): `package==1.0`

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
pip install <package name==version no*>
```

for instance

```
pip install musdb==0.2.*
```

That would pin your package

Comment: Please see the official documentation
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#:~:text=Pinning%20a%20package%20specification%20in,you%20do%20not%20want%20updated.

Comment: It's related to conda pm not pip.