# GLIBC_2.12 Issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

Over the past year or so, I have been encountering a problem when trying to add either GDAL or Iris on top of the Anaconda distribution. I receive the error message:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5a7197379ef6> in <module>()
----> 1 from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

ImportError: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /usr/local/other/SSSO_Ana-PyD/4.3.1_py2.7_gcc-5.3-sp3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/../../.././libglib-2.0.so.0)
```

I have a similar problem with PyQt5. I am wondering is someone has a clue on how to resolve the issue.

I am working on a 64-bit Linux system and I have been having the problem with Anaconda 4.2.0 (and any newer version).

Any pointer will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f